# HTML5 validator.w3.org

Tags: html

My site was valid until today, wondering wether it is my site's or the validator's fault.

I am getting this message:

> The error encountered was: 500 Can't connect to localhost:8888 (connect: Connection refused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP Error 500 is an Internal Server Error, so that will be their fault. Try validator.nu whilst you are waiting.

Answer (score 3):

W3C validator maintainer here. Tip: Next time you see that message, try validating your document directly at http://validator.w3.org/nu/ instead.

Because if you see that 500 error it means the validator is trying to reach the HTML5 backend, which runs as a separate service/process responding at localhost:8888 on the validator host.

But we actually run several validator hosts, round-robin, so if you see that 500 error it could mean that only one of the HTML5 backends on one of the hosts is temporarily down. And if you go to http://validator.w3.org/nu/ you might get lucky and hit a different host and it'll work.

On the other hand if you get a 404 from http://validator.w3.org/nu/ 
it most likely means you caught me in the middle of restarting/redeploying the W3C HTML5 validator backends to pull in changes I've made to the sources from https://github.com/validator/validator

But that never takes me more than a few minutes, so on your end you should never be seeing that 500 error for more than, say, 10 minutes at most. So if/when you do see it for any longer than that, please report it either by tweeting to @w3c or @sideshowbarker on twitter, or pinging me on IRC (MikeSmith on #whatwg or #w3c on irc.freenode.net).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty clear from the error that it's a problem at their end:

> Checking the Document Type of this document **requires the help of an external tool which was either not enabled in this validator, or is currently unavailable**. Check in the validator's system configuration that HTML5 Validator is enabled and functional.
>   The error encountered was: 500 Can't connect to localhost:8888 (connect: Connection refused)

(My emphasis.) I expect they'll get it fixed Right Quick Like.

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the following error while checking the domain in W3C  validator and we managed to fix it by installing CA Bundle and Intermediate Root certificates for the same domain. Now, the domain is able to pass through the W3C validation check and reporting appropriate result.

```
===================================
Sorry! This document cannot be checked.

Error

I got the following unexpected response when trying to retrieve <https://our-xx-domain.in/>:

    500 Can't connect to our-xx-domain.in:443

If you made recent changes to your domain name (DNS) configuration, you may also want to check that your domain records are correct, or ask your hosting company to do so.
===================================
```